# Как лучше поднять мобильный прокси (с динамическим адресом) для подключение к нему удалено?

Tags: linux, сервер, proxy, vpn

Есть:

1. raspberry pi 3
2. Модем HUAWEI E8372
3. Симка МТС
4. Кабельный (домашний) интернет со статическим IP

Как лучше поднять мобильный прокси (с динамическим адресом) для подключение к нему удалено? Получиться это реализовать?

Проси необходим для продвижение инстаграм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, используйте [Dynamic DNS сервисы](https://www.maketecheasier.com/best-dynamic-dns-providers/), благо этого добра хватает, с доменами на любой вкус.

Comment: Правильно понял, что с Dynamic DNS сервисами для реализации мобильного прокси  отпадает необходимость в кабельном интернете с выделенным IP? Подключаю мобильный модем к raspberry синхронизирую с Dynamic DNS сервисом и готово?

Comment: Да, ставите клиент DDNS на малинку, при смене IP, она сообщает DDNS сервису о том что айпи сменился. Вы всё верно поняли.